# rewrite file.php to folder like /file/ with htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use some of my .php files to act like they are folders.

I have this files:
file1.php
file2.php
file3.php

When I open my website.com/file1/, i want it to show file1.php.

So I found this:

```
RewriteRule ^file1*$.* file1.php [NC]
```

It basically do this with file1.php. But it also rewrites file1.php when you enter website.com/file10 or website.com/file1000

I don't want it to be open all variations starting with file1*.

I just want to have website.com/file1 and website.com/file1/ to open file1.php.

Can you help me to make it?

Comment: Please start reading about the basics of "regular expressions" to understand how that matching works. You will be able to work from there yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below rewrite rule and test.

```
RewriteEngine  on
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```